# Unique id consisting of only numbers

Tags: php, unique

I need to get **time** based *unique* id which would only consist of numbers, i was thinking to simply use something like this:

```
str_replace(".", "", microtime(true))
```

I would use this id for many things, for example comments posting, and i'm expecting quite high traffic so i would like to know how high are the chances of collision with `microtime` function?

And perhaps there is a better way to get numerical unique id? Just remember that it has to based on time so sorting could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use a pure time based ID you need to ensure that you avoid collisions so a) use a primary key in the database and then b) use a recursive check to ensure that your time based ID has not already been taken:

```
$id = getTimeId();

function getTimeId() {
    // Generate microtime
    // Query to ensure it does not exist
    // Return microtime
}
```

I shall leave it upto you good sir to enjoy making it recursive.

Comment: Database transactions will also help in a situation like this. It depends on the traffic as to how many users will see a collision error.

Answer (score 23):

you can use this to get uniqid but is not numberic:

```
$id = uniqid(); //58aea16085f6b
```

use this to convert it to only numbers:

```
$id = hexdec( uniqid() ); //1560112880181100
```

if it's too long use this but maybe get negetive numbers:

```
$id = crc32( uniqid() ); //-1551585806
```

if you just need posetive numbers you can do it:

```
$id = abs( crc32( uniqid() ) ); //1551585806
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @JamesAMohler A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: What do we include to get hexdec? / uniqid/ etc etc?

Answer (score 5):

If it must be based on time you could use microtime. But I guess you are storing things in a database so my vote would go for a `primary key` column `Id` with `auto_increment` and then a second column with `timestamp` type and a default `current time`.

Then you can sort on timestamp and also have a 100% unique identifier even with extremely high traffic. But if ordering is needed (so not searching between dates) then you dont need it based on time.

1, 2, 3, 4 will be in the same order as a microtime key thats just a lot larger and further appart.

UPDATE

If it must be a unique key and cant be used from the database, try the following. The changes of a duplicate key are so slim it can be ignored.

```
$key = microtime() + floor(rand()*10000);
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm not using mysql. However i do use database called Cassandra which doesn't support things you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to avoid collisions time based won't work. eventually you'll get a collision.  Why not use a counter with a semaphore.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php